# How to update a rails 5 variable using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application using Rails 5 and I have an article resource and I'm implementing "like/unlike" function. I already got that function but I'm having troubles on updating the `@artlike` variable on the view. These are my files:

show.html.erb:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> <span id="likes"><%= render partial: "likes", locals: {artlike: @artlike} %></span>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
respond_to :js

def like
  puts "LikesController:like"
  @usuario = current_usuario
  @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
  @usuario.like!(@articulo)
  @artlike = Like.where(articulo_id: @articulo.id).count
end

def unlike
  puts "LikesController:unlike"
  @usuario = current_usuario
  @like = @usuario.likes.find_by_articulo_id(params[:id])
  @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
  @like.destroy!
  @artlike = Like.where(articulo_id: @articulo.id).count
end
```

_likes.html.erb:

```
<span id="likes"><%= @artlike %></span>
```

like.js.erb File

```
$('span#likes').html('<%= j render partial: "likes", locals: {artlike: @artlike} %>');
```

How can I do the `@artlike` value in the view?

---

This is the ouput in the console log:

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TPYI.png)

Comment: @dlvgn have you try this and see if it works, if it does I can add it as answer. `<% js = escape_javascript(render partial: "likes", locals: {artlike: @artlike}) ) %>
$("span#likes").html("<%= js %>");` in your view: `<span id="likes"><%=
 render partial: "likes", locals: {artlike: @artlike} %></span>`

Comment: Hey @user6589814 i put this in the like.js.erb file `<% js = escape_javascript(render partial: "likes", locals: {artlike: @artlike}) ) %> 
$('span#likes').html('<%= js %>');` and in the partial _likes.html.erb i put only the variable `<%= @artlike %>`. In the view i put the code that you told me but  it doesn'y work yet

Comment: @dlvgn. Do you get any error or what happens?

Comment: @Rubioli No, I don't. The console just show the insertion in my like/unlike function, but there isn't an error related about the variable update.

Comment: @dlvgn could you show the current snip you have + the controller code. in your controller, what do you respond with?

Comment: @Rubioli I edited my question.

Comment: Show the console log

Comment: Do you have multiple span#likes in the DOM? Perhaps for different responsive views? Try to change it to span#likes1 in both the js.erb and the view and see if it starts working.

Comment: @dlvngn First I wouldn't use `id` cause if you have multiple `span#likes` it wouldn't work correctly. For approaching your issue there is two ways you can do. One would be this way and try to get it work and other way would be try to get what this would do but in `jQuery`. Results would be exactly the same. Basically what js.erb is doing is the same as `jquery`. What you think?

Comment: did my comment above solve the issue?

Comment: No, I don't have more span elements.